# Simulating CMIS Atom API doesn't load the information properly

Tags: alfresco, atom-feed, cmis, opencmis

I was requested to simulate a CMIS Atom API for my company's content management using our API. but I'm stuck in what it seems to be something simple. So I'm trying to load the CMIS TCK, but for some reason the values of the responses doesn't make it into the next request. So I think I'm missing something.

The first request I get is to getRepositories

```
/cmisatom/getRepositories
```

Then I get the request to get a specific repository

```
/cmisatom/getRepositories?repositoryId=c9ad76c6-d121-4a32-bb14-e5d43bf91ee6
```

Which kinda tells me that the data from the first request was parsed properly.

Now on the third request is where things get weird. I get the request for the id

```
/cmisatom/c9ad76c6-d121-4a32-bb14-e5d43bf91ee6/id?id=&filter=&includeAllowableActions=&includeACL=&includePolicyIds=&includeRelationships=&renditionFilter=
```

but no information of the id, not filter nor anything else, was loaded. I'm matching the responses to a alfresco CMIS Atom that I have running on my local. So the response its identical except for the jsession. Can you share any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

The steps go like below.

1. Service document is the first one to fetch - your example refers to it as "/cmisatom/getRepositories". This lists the list of all repository data. It also includes the repository url templates like OBJECT_BY_ID, TYPE_BY_ID etc. That means, for navigation / listing folders etc, your link "/cmisatom/getRepositories?id=c9ad76c6-d121-4a32-bb14-e5d43bf91ee6" is not used.
2. The third link you're referring to looks like a URL template OBJECT_BY_ID - and here you have to provide the object id and populate other params before you make a request.
3. The param object id for the first request is again a value which you obtain from service document. This value is called ROOT FOLDER ID.
4. Use root folder id to update object by id url template and get the root folder details - from there you get the children and proceed further.

You can refer further to Apache Chemistry In Memory repository - https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/repositories/dev-repositories-inmemory.html - it is an open source implementation which can help you dig deep.

And this is the spec: http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html